# Using async await in recursive function with process.nextTick()

Tags: node.js, async-await, lifecycle, event-loop

I have a working recursive function in a node.js app that uses Promises with a process.nextTick() callback. I am curious how this would/could work with async await.

I've tried a few different things but no matter what I've done the async function returns to the calling function before all the nextTick callbacks have completed.

non-working (delete cache called from express route)

```
const deleteCache = async () => {
  try {
    const cacheRef = fsDb.collection('Cache');
    return await deleteDocsBatch(cacheRef, 30);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('error in deleteCache:' + e);
  }
};

const deleteDocsBatch = async (cacheRef, batchSize) => {
  try {
    // get all the cached docs, limit to 30 to avoid potential memory issues
    const snapShot = await cacheRef.limit(batchSize).get();
    if (snapShot.size === 0) { return; }

    const batch = fsDb.batch();
    snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      batch.delete(doc.ref);
    });

    await batch.commit();
    process.nextTick(() => {
      deleteDocsBatch(cacheRef, batchSize);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('error in deleteDocsBatch:' + e);
  }
};
```

working:

```
function deleteCollection (batchSize) {
  var collectionRef = fsDb.collection('Cache');
  var query = collectionRef.orderBy('__name__').limit(batchSize);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deleteQueryBatch(fsDb, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
  });
}

function deleteQueryBatch (db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject) {
  query.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      // When there are no documents left, we are done
      if (snapshot.size === 0) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(0); });
      }

      // Delete documents in a batch
      var batch = db.batch();
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        batch.delete(doc.ref);
      });

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        batch.commit().then(() => {
          resolve(snapshot.size);
        })
          .catch(reject);
      });
    }).then((numDeleted) => {
      if (numDeleted === 0) {
        resolve();
        return;
      }

      // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
      // exploding the stack.
      process.nextTick(() => {
        deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
      });
    })
    .catch(reject);
}
```

Is it possible to write this recursive function with nexttick() using async await?

original firestore code sample:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so take advantage of the fact that when you attach anything to a Promise via `.then()` then it will run in next tick. In other words your `process.nextTick` is not even necessary in your original code. In worst case you will go into recursive call but exit immediatly. Never going beyond depth 1.

And `await` is a syntactic sugar for `.then()`. Under the hood the code is transformed into series of `.then()` anyway. So this

```
await deleteDocsBatch(cacheRef, batchSize);
```

instead of

```
process.nextTick(() => {
  deleteDocsBatch(cacheRef, batchSize);
});
```

**should be enough**. The initial synchronous part (i.e. up until first await) of the function will run recursively though as I've mentioned. So if you want to really be sure then you can force asynchronity via

```
await Promise.resolve();
await deleteDocsBatch(cacheRef, batchSize);
```

The point is that you tell the interpreter "hey, this is an asynchronity point, go do something else, like nothing, ok?".

Also note that `await new Promise(res => process.nextTick(res));` is an alternative. Although an overkill.

---

An example:

```
async function p1() {
    console.log('interrupt');
};

async function p2() {
    console.log('1');
    await Promise.resolve();
    console.log('2');
};

p2();
p1();
```

So as you can see both functions are actually synchronous. Except that `p2` is not because it has `await` inside. And that `await` forces everything below onto next tick allowing `p1` to run in between. The `p2` function is equivalent to

```
function p2() {
    console.log('1');
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        console.log('2');
    });
};
```

and the output is:

```
1
interrupt
2
```

---

And another example. This exceeds maximum recursion depth very fast:

```
async function go(i)
{
  console.log(i);
  go(i+1);
}

go(0);
```

This does not. Ever.

```
async function go(i)
{
  console.log(i);
  await Promise.resolve();
  go(i+1);
}

go(0);
```

The second code actually uses a constant amount of memory.

---

**Conclusion:** any (reachable) `await` inside a function will break the recursive call. And this is how the code may look like:

```
const deleteDocsBatch = async (cacheRef, batchSize) => {
  try {
    // get all the cached docs, limit to 30 to avoid potential memory issues
    const snapShot = await cacheRef.limit(batchSize).get();
    if (snapShot.size === 0) { return; }

    const batch = fsDb.batch();
    snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      batch.delete(doc.ref);
    });

    await batch.commit();
    await deleteDocsBatch(cacheRef, batchSize);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('error in deleteDocsBatch:' + e);
  }
};
```

and the only recursive issue you should worry about is the stop condition (as in: are there cases when that function never ends?). That code won't eat your memory.

Comment: Wasn't me that downvoted. I tried the await Promise.resolve(); and the 'overkill' and neither had the desired effect. In both cases some nexticks were run after the parent function returned to the caller.

Comment: @RichWilliams I've added full code at the end. Are you saying this code produces some execution in background after it exits? Sounds unlikely. Unless `batch.delete()` is asynchronous? (I don't know what lib that is)